# how to save a value in sqlite database which coming from webserver in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am creating application in which i post the data to server some username and password
for save the this data in webserver database through the http
  it working proper 
   but my next work is if i submit the data on server then server pass the json value for me to save that json value in local database in iphone 
value mean which i submit on server database through http i want same value on sqlite database in local but using json i dont know how to use json in iphone please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to iterate through the JSON response like you would an XML file, and store the information in an array, then insert that array into an SQLite database.

This site should help you with the JSON parsing http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c

and if you're looking for a good SQLite objective C wrapper use FMDB. it will cut a lot of boiler plate code out. https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 0):

use this URl and implement this concept on  your project

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/